# Tab layout with custom indicator

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How to make tab layout with this custom indicator like this image?

[image]

Comment: please add what you are tried?

Comment: check this https://github.com/hackware1993/MagicIndicator

Comment: i tried to give the tab layout as back ground but it doesn't work (as custom shape). as it work with tabs background only not tab indicator

Comment: i think magic indicator won't work with me

Comment: all i need is to make custom shape on tab indicator, i have searched a lot, but didn't find a way to give custom shape to indicator , only you can give tabs custom background , not it's indicator

Answer (score 1):

then set tabIndicator in the layout:

app:tabIndicator="@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_24dp" // Your Custom indicator design image

Or in styles.xml:

@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_24dp

Comment: It work, but when given it custom shape , the un- selected tab doesn't have its back ground